# Open pdf inside iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, iframe

I want to open PDF file in inframe inside asp.net page.
I tried this

```
<iframe src="http://samplepdf.com/sample.pdf" width="400px" height="300px"  />
```

This works fine.

However, when I change Path to PDF file as following

```
<iframe id ="myframe" src=@"C:\Book.pdf" width="400px" height="300px"  runat="server"/>
```

Nothing is displayed inside frame.

I tried change path in CodeBehind as following

```
myframe.Attributes.Add("src", @"C:\Book.pdf");
```

But pdf file is not opened inside iframe.
What is a problem?
Does some know solution?

Comment: Have you tried using a file:///-style URL?

Answer (score 4):

HTML cannot interact with filepaths on the local disk.

You need to reference the PDF file using a path within your web server.